# conditional formatting UI

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

The app I'm working on is a calculator basically. What i want to do is to is set up something so that on the results screen if the answers all = 60 or higher a big green check (an image I'll place in) appears and some text above or below that says you passes. If not I want a red X to appear that says you fail.

I know this should be simple I just don't know where to look to get the answers. If someone could point me in the right direction with a link or something so i can read up on this that would great. because i have tried looking but i just don't know what to look for to be honest.

Comment: Does the user enter numbers in the fields?

Comment: yes the user enters numbers into the text field. Calculations are done on those numbers that are entered. and then a score comes up on the results screen and that is where i want the green check or red x to pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically just need to get the text from the `UITextField` as an integer like so:

```
int sumOfFields += [[myUITextField text] intValue];
```

You would do that for all of your fields. Then you need to check if it's greater than or equal to 60 or not:

```
if (sumOfFields >= 60) {
    [self setValidationUI:TRUE];
}
else {
    [self setValidationUI:FALSE];
}
```

Where `setValidationUI` is a method that takes a boolean value that determines wether it should show the big green checkmark or a bit red X like so:

```
-(void)setValidationUI:(BOOL)isValid {
    if (isValid) {
        [resultsImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"]];
        [resultsTextField setText:@"You Passed!"];
    }
    else {
        [resultsImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BigUglyRedX.png"]];
        [resultsTextField setText:@"You Fail..."];
    }
}
```

header file

```
- (void)setValidationUI:(bool)isValid;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultsImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *resultsLabel;
```

Comment: Ok i understand taking the text that will show up in my labels on the results screen and setting them to an integer. Then have the if / else statement to check if it is >= 60. But the "setValidationUI" how does that display a green check or red x? if i am going to be importing those 2 images into my project. how does "setValidationUI" call those images to be displayed and where would it display them?

Comment: @Shaun: I've updated my code with a function like I was talking about. Does it all make sense now?

Comment: Yes i think so. So the -(void) would go in my app delegate.h & .m ?? and then what ever image placeholder and textfeild or label i have setup on my results screen i link them that method in IB?

Comment: Yes, you need to put the method name `-(void)setValidationUI:(BOOL)isValid;` in the header, and the whole method in the m file. And then replace `resultsImage` and `resultsTextField` with the names you gave to those views in Interface Builder.

Comment: ok Thanks ill try n see what i can put together.. ill let you know how it works out

Comment: I put everything in but in the method it says use of undeclared identifier "resultsImage" and "resultsLabel" ? i named them in IB. Am i suppose to do soemthing else?

Comment: You need them named in Interface Builder. Then you need to add properties to the view that uses them: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myImageView;` Of course use your name for the views instead of 'myImageView'.

Comment: @Free Thanks.. I had to add an IBOutlet to the property and connect them in IB for it to work. But everything else was spot on.. Thanks again for your help :)